# Jquery mobile 1.4 data-enhance=false don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to update my JQM app from 1.3 to 1.4, and on some element, data-enhance="false" doesn't work anymore… The elements remains enhanced…

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/matthieubrunet/RB9Qw/

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>JQM 1.4.3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="yes" id="yes" data-enhance="false" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to activate the ignoreContentEnabled option, but it doesn't work :

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
```

Is it a bug, or am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: isn't it named `data-enhanceD`? By default it is set to false, so JQM kicks in and does the enhancement. If you do it yourself, you should set it `<el data-enhanced="true">`. But note that currently not all widgets have this option implemented.

Comment: No. it is `data-enhance` only, and not `data-enhanced`

Comment: data-enhanced is a new options in 1.4, that is designed to flag the manually enhanced elements. It could work in my case, except the element is considered by JQM as enhanced. Data-enhance remains in the documentation : http://api.jquerymobile.com/data-attribute/

Comment: use `$.mobile.keepNative`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/egD6q/

Comment: indeed. Or just data-role="none". But it doesn't explain why data-enhance doesn't work… Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put your script

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
});
```

just before loading jquery mobile js. official docs state that mobileinit gets called as soon as jquery mobile js gets loaded : http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

Therefor the order should be:

jquery.js -> mobileinit binding script-> jquery.mobile.js